# remove duplicate values of only one column value from all the available columns in sql query

Tags: sql-server, distinct-values

I have a sql query with three columns .I want to remove any duplicate value exits in beam_current column.How to do so.I work in sql-server2012

I used Distinct but then also I'm getting duplicate values of beam_current.
My sql Query is-

```
select DISTINCT (beam_current), logtime, beam_energy 
from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT 
where logtime between '2014-08-09 01:13:03' and '2014-08-09 02:16:53'
      and (beam_current like '%9.96' 
           or beam_current like '%9.97' 
           ... etc ...) 
      and beam_energy between '550' and '552'
```

**EDIT-1**
My output is-

[image]

In first column 29.98 is repeating thrice.I only want any one of the row corresponding to 29.98.How to do that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return 1 row for each value of beam_current:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
  row_number() over (partition by beam_current order by (select 1)) rn,
  beam_current, logtime, beam_energy 
FROM INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT 
WHERE 
  logtime between '2014-08-09 01:13:03' and '2014-08-09 02:16:53'
  and (beam_current like '%9.96' or beam_current like '%9.97' 
       or beam_current like '%9.98' or  beam_current like '%9.99'
       or beam_current like '%0' or beam_current like '%_0.01' 
       or beam_current like '%_0.02' or beam_current like '%_0.03' 
       or beam_current like '%_0.04' or beam_current like '%_0.05' 
       or beam_current like '%_0.06') 
       and beam_energy between 550 and 552
)
SELECT beam_current, logtime, beam_energy 
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: This should get more credit, this worked great for my case. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The `distinct` keyword works on the entire row (all columns), so:

```
select DISTINCT (beam_current), logtime, beam_energy
```

is the same as:

```
select DISTINCT beam_current, logtime, beam_energy
```

is the same as:

```
select DISTINCT ((beam_current)), (logtime), (((((beam_energy)))))
```

You can use `row_number()` to select only the latest row per value of `beam_energy`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by beam_current
                    order by logtime desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT 
        where   logtime between '2014-08-09 01:13:03' and '2014-08-09 02:16:53'
                and (beam_current like '%9.96' 
                    or beam_current like '%9.97' 
                    ... etc ...) 
                and beam_energy between '550' and '552'
        ) numbered_rows
where   rn = 1 -- Latest row per beam_current
```

Comment: ,Please see my edit.When I apply the sql query as you said,Then also I'm getting duplicate values of first column i.e my beam current.I only want one row corresponding to one value of beam_current.

Comment: Right, so you're looking for one row per `beam_current` value, instead of per `logtime, beam_energy` group. I've updated the answer.

Comment: If I have the following query, then how to convert into above like query. query is **select b.logtime, b.beam_current, b.beam_energy,CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag9_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag9_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag9_rb from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT b INNER JOIN(INDUS2_VACUUM.dbo.main_vacuum_analog c inner join INDUS2_VACUUM.dbo.main_vacuum_status a on c.logtime=a.logtime)
ON a.LOGTIME = b.LOGTIME and (b.beam_current like '%9.96' etc)and b.logtime between '' and '' b.beam_current in('10','20') and (b.beam_energy between '' and '' ) order by b.logtime**

Comment: How to apply the above said sql query on inner join and case statements in sql .Example of the query I have given in above statement.

Comment: What is numbered_rows means??

Comment: `numbered_rows` is an alias for the subquery (like `cte` in t.clausen-dk's example)  You can give it any name, like `dcct_with_numbers`

Answer (score 2):

It seems a single row combination is distinct for each value of beam_current.
If you will try only
    `select Distinct(beam_current) from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT where ....` 
then only you will get that unique value.

Group by  will also not work because it will group the columns from left to right written after group by keyword.So anyhow you will get the same result.