# SQL Server Set with duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, unique, recordset

I have a doubt in how to send a query to a database that gives me a set of records that might include duplicates of a certain value in just one column on the set and from those records I need it to give the whole set but just with one record from each of the repeated records. The `DISTINCT` doesn't work well for me, because the whole record overall might be different. For example when I ask for the result set it gives the following:

```
╔═════════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ ContratctNumber ║ BusinessType ║ PersonType ║
╠═════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║           12345 ║            1 ║          1 ║
║           23455 ║            3 ║          1 ║
║          275479 ║            1 ║          2 ║
║          275479 ║            2 ║          1 ║
║          275479 ║            3 ║          2 ║
║          234576 ║            2 ║          1 ║
║           78656 ║            1 ║          1 ║
║            5678 ║            3 ║          1 ║
║            5678 ║            2 ║          1 ║
╚═════════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

And what I need as a result is the following:

```
╔═════════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ ContratctNumber ║ BusinessType ║ PersonType ║
╠═════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║           12345 ║            1 ║          1 ║
║           23455 ║            3 ║          1 ║
║          275479 ║            1 ║          2 ║
║          234576 ║            2 ║          1 ║
║           78656 ║            1 ║          1 ║
║            5678 ║            3 ║          1 ║
╚═════════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

As you see it gives me all the set, but for the repeated records that have the same ContractNumber it just gives the first records that appears on the table.

I would appreciate your help on this one since I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you define *first* in the table? Do you have a date column that you could use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove duplicate values of only one column value from all the available columns in sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694871/remove-duplicate-values-of-only-one-column-value-from-all-the-available-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number` with customized ordering.  This query will return one row per unique combination of identifiers in the `partition` clause.  When more than one row exists, it will choose the lowest BusinessType.

```
; with CTE as (
    select *
    , row_number() over (partition by ContractNumber, Person Type 
                         order by BusinessType) as RN
    from MyTable)

Select * from CTE where RN = 1
```

If you are not comfortable with CTEs, you can apply the same logic with a temp table or subquery instead.